# Oracle SQL rounding misbehavior

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, rounding

I encountered a strange behavior of the `binary_double` rounding with Oracle SQL. `binary_double` values should be rounded `half even` according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm), but when testing this with the following queries, it seems that there are some inconsistencies. **All the queries below should give the same last digit**, respectively, i.e., 0.x00008 and 0.x00006 (rounded to 6 digits) or 0.x0008 and 0.x0006 (rounded to 5 digits) with x in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). **Problem is that they do not**. Any help on understanding why the rounding results depend on the first digit after the seperator point and/or the number of digits in the original number is kindly appreciated.

```
select 1,(round( cast (0.0000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.0000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 2,(round( cast (0.1000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.1000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 3,(round( cast (0.2000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.2000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 4,(round( cast (0.3000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.3000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 5,(round( cast (0.4000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.4000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 6,(round( cast (0.5000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.5000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 7,(round( cast (0.6000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.6000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 8,(round( cast (0.7000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.7000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 9,(round( cast (0.8000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.8000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 10,(round( cast (0.9000075 as binary_double ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.9000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) from dual
  union
  select 11,(round( cast (0.000075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.000065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual
  union
  select 12,(round( cast (0.100075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.100065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual
  union
  select 13,(round( cast (0.200075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.200065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual
  union
  select 14,(round( cast (0.300075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.300065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual
  union
  select 15,(round( cast (0.400075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.400065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual
  union
  select 16,(round( cast (0.500075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.500065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual
  union
  select 17,(round( cast (0.600075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.600065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual
  union
  select 18,(round( cast (0.700075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.700065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual
  union
  select 19,(round( cast (0.800075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.800065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual
  union
  select 20,(round( cast (0.900075 as binary_double ) ,5)), (round( cast (0.900065 as binary_double ) ,5)) from dual;
```

The bottom line, is this:
Why in the following query, there is a difference between the two values:

```
SELECT (round( CAST (0.0000065 AS BINARY_DOUBLE ) ,6)), (round( cast (0.1000065 as binary_double ) ,6)) FROM dual;
```

Following @zerkms advice, I [convert](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html?decimal=048046049048048048048054053) the numbers into binary format, and I get:

```
0.0000065 -> 6.49999999999999959998360846147E-6
0.1000065 -> 1.00006499999999998173905169097E-1
```

The query rounds this up to 6 digits. Surprisingly, for me, I see that the rounding results in:

```
0.0000065 -> 0.000006 (execute the query above to see this)
0.1000065 -> 0.100007 (execute the query above to see this)
```

Why is that? I could understand, if I'd try round to >12 digits, where the series of digits in the binary representation start to differ, but how come the difference becomes visible on such early stage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's have a look at the first example, since others are pretty much the similar:

The `0.0000075` in double precision IEEE 754 is presented as `7.50000000000000019000643072808E-6`

The `0.0000065` is presented as `6.49999999999999959998360846147E-6`

When you round both by 6 - the former becomes `8e-6`, the latter `6e-6`

There is no "consistent" behaviour, because different numbers are factorized to divisors of 2 differently.

So, even though when you do `SELECT 0.0000065 FROM DUAL` and see `0.0000065` as a result - it's not how it's represented internally in a binary form, it's already "broken" and less than that number by a tiny fraction. Then it's rounded for you during output formatting.

The double IEEE 754 provides [15-16 significant digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation). So for output purposes they become: `7.500000000000000e-6` and `6.499999999999999e-6` which is rounded to `6.5e-6`

**UPD**:

`6.49999999999999959998360846147E-6` == `0.00000649999999999999959998360846147`. If you round it by 6 - it equals to `0.000006`, because it's followed by `4` which is less than `5`

`1.00006499999999998173905169097E-1` == `0.100006499999999998173905169097` is rounded by 6 to `0.100006`, because the next digit is `4`, that is less than `5`. And I see the difference with actual result. And honestly I don't have a good explanation here. I suspect it's an oracle issue, since:

- C# runs "as expected": http://ideone.com/Py9aer
- Go also runs "as expected": http://ideone.com/OEJBoA
- Python also runs "as expected": http://ideone.com/I0ADOR
- Javascript (in console): `parseFloat(0.1000065).toFixed(6) // 0.100006`

**UPD 2**:

after even more research with fellows from a skype chat I've been given a good example that the result depends on the rounding mode chosen:

```
flock.core> (import '[org.apache.commons.math3.util Precision])

flock.core> (Precision/round (Double. 0.1000065) 6 BigDecimal/ROUND_CEILING)
0.100007
flock.core> (Precision/round (Double. 0.1000065) 6 BigDecimal/ROUND_DOWN)
0.100006
flock.core> (Precision/round (Double. 0.1000065) 6 BigDecimal/ROUND_UP)
0.100007
flock.core> (Precision/round (Double. 0.1000065) 6 BigDecimal/ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
0.100006
flock.core> (Precision/round (Double. 0.1000065) 6 BigDecimal/ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
0.100006
flock.core> (Precision/round (Double. 0.1000065) 6 BigDecimal/ROUND_HALF_UP)
0.100007
flock.core> (Precision/round (Double. 0.1000065) 6 BigDecimal/ROUND_FLOOR)
0.100006
```

**Conclusion**:

there is no "correct" or "incorrect" result in this case, they are all correct and strongly depend on the implementation (+ options you use when you perform arithmetic operations).

References:

- Online decimal to IEEE 754 double converter: [0.0000065](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046048048048048048054053) and [0.0000075](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046048048048048048055053)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation

Comment: Thank you, getting there, but still... I edited the question as per your comment, please have a look. I claim that still there is something wrong.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: hold for a second though. The last `0.1000065` result doesn't follow the expectations :-(

Comment: Exactly, that's my point. I ran a Java code where the rounding works also as expected and then faced the problem of diffs against the Oracle. The problem remains unsolved... Much appreciate the effort!

Comment: @Simon Righley: in java there is no "real" rounding. You mix multiple operations (multiplication and division), which affects the precision. Fortunately it affects it to the "expected" side, but it shouldn't be treated as the case.

Comment: Was referring to this documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN

Comment: @Simon Righley: according to that documentation it must be `0.100006`. Added examples on Go and python, that also return the expected value. So I suspect it's just Oracle corp implementation, that both affects jvm and oracle dbms.

Answer (score 1):

You should better use the DECIMAL data type to avoid rounding issues.

More info here : http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj15260.html

Try this one:

```
select 1,round(cast (0.0000075 as decimal(15,7)),6), round(cast (0.0000065 as decimal(15,7)),6) from dual;
```

Since I have no Oracle database installed, I could not test it but it should work.

One important remark: if decimal has a scale smaller than the actual number, exceeding decimals will be truncated. So you might want to cast to decimal (17,8) for more security.

Comment: Thank you, but the link is not working, could you please fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That is because `binary_double` is a floating point data type, and isn't always (or always isn't) accurate.

See [this related article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i140176) from Oracle on floating point data types.

Comment: OK, but so always is not (accurate) any floating point data type in Java, C, etc., and still I can enforce a consistent rounding rule, whereas with the examples above, it seems like in Oracle there is no rounding pattern at all. Or do I miss something?

Comment: You are casting your `number` to `binary_double`. That's where you lose your accuracy.

Comment: @Simon Righley: floating point number (single precision) cannot guarantee precision for more than 6 significant digits. It's by design (IEEE 754) and it will behave the same way in any correct implementation, including Java and whatnot.

Comment: @zerkms The examples are with 5 digits too, so this isn't a valid argument

Comment: @PatrickHofman OK, but casting needs to follow some rules, doesn't it? If I cast 0.100075 to binary double, why shouldn't I expect to arrive at 0.100075 but rather 0.100076 or 0.100074? I would understand this point, if the examples above would show some consistent behavior, but to me it seems that they do not.

Comment: That's the entire problem with floats. You can't rely on it that it is saved *exactly* that way.

Comment: 0.100075 cannot be expressed accurately in binary, so no matter how much precision you have, a binary float value will always be a little bit larger or smaller than 0.100075.

Comment: @PatrickHofman just a notification about the significant update in my answer, if you are still curious :-)

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks a lot for the pingback. Didn't read your last update yet, but was still hooked on. Sorry, but can't upvote you twice ;)

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: I wish I could upvote myself :-D Learned a lot during investigation